# Translating interface - same word duplication

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have "problem" i want to do one word translation e.g. 'Location' (same case) I use that word with t() function in (menu, module, template tpl, taxonomy) when I go to translate interface it show me same string: 4x"Built-in interface", 2x"taxonomy", 1x"fields". I have 4 languages and I have repeat everything for same word. Is it possible to do one translation and Drupal apply on all exact strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to translate each of these strings individually. It is not enough to do it only once.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to translate it only once; Drupal will use that translation for all strings that are the same.

Comment: take look at pictures http://s13.postimage.org/i17kcosev/strings.jpg"